# DynamoDB many-to-many equivalent

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb

I want to replicate the following relations in DynamoDB

> A user can have many medals
>
> A medal can be granted to many users

I read that you should only use a single table in DynamoDB, but I haven't thought of a solution to the problem yet.

My first thought was to create a medals table, and then in the users table, let the users have a list of medal IDs.

This requires more requests to the database and still doesn't sound good.

Any advice?

Comment: I think that this post will answer your question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48537284/how-to-handle-many-to-many-in-dynamodb

Comment: @mxmissile why couldn't a Global Secondary Index on the users table handle the "all users with a gold medal" query?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Amazon DynamoDB and relationship many-to-many](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11224855/amazon-dynamodb-and-relationship-many-to-many)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Relational Database**

For a simple use case on a regular `Relational Database` settings this can be achieved with:

```
Users

ID  | Name
----+---------------
U01 | John
----+---------------
U02 | Richard


Medals

ID  | Name        | Points
----+-------------+--------
M01 | Gold        | 500
----+-------------+--------
M02 | Sliver      | 200


Users_Medals

User ID  | Medal ID | Attainment
---------+----------+-------------
U01      | M01      | Apr 2, 2019
---------+----------+-------------
U01      | M02      | Jun 3, 2019
---------+----------+-------------
U02      | M02      | Jun 2, 2019
```

**DynamoDB**

However with `DynamoDB`, the objective is to flatten out data for fast retrieval (single digit milliseconds) via the `Hash Key` (think of it as a Primary Key), there are strictly no joins across tables in DynamoDB

Data is slightly duplicated (i.e. Medal Name is duplicated for each user) which is likely to involve a heavy penalty during `update`, `delete` (i.e. if Medal Name needs to be changed from 'Gold' to 'Platinum' later, all records need to be scanned for and updated individually)

```
<!-- Hash and Range Key -->

Users_Medals

User ID (HashKey)  | Medal ID (Range Key) | Medal Name  | Attainment
-------------------+----------------------+-------------+--------------
U01                | M01                  | Gold        | Jun 3, 2019
-------------------+----------------------+-------------+--------------
U01                | M02                  | Silver      | Jun 2, 2019
-------------------+----------------------+-------------+--------------
U02                | M02                  | Gold        | Apr 1, 2019


<!--- Hash Key Only --->

Users_Medals

UserID_MedalID (HashKey) | Medal Name  | Attainment
-------------------------+-------------+--------------
U01#M01                  | Gold        | Jun 3, 2019
-------------------------+-------------+--------------
U01#M02                  | Silver      | Jun 2, 2019
-------------------------+-------------+--------------
U02#M02                  | Gold        | Apr 1, 2019
```

Aim to structure your tables and application data for fast retrieval, hope this gives you an idea

**Updates**

If your Application has a requirement to display or get list of Medals, then a separate Standalone `Medals` Table should be used

```
Medals

ID (Hash Key)  | Name        | Points
---------------+-------------+--------
M01            | Gold        | 500
---------------+-------------+--------
M02            | Sliver      | 200
---------------+-------------+--------
M03            | Bronze      | 200
```

To get a complete list of Medals, a `Scan` is needed

To get the details of a Medal (i.e. Name, Points) by the ID (Hash Key), `Get Item` should be used

Comment: I like this answer a lot, one question though, what should I use to list all the medal names without duplicates?

Comment: Thanks. I updated my answer, I would use a standalone table `Medals` for this purpose, and not try to do a `select distinct(medal_name) from Users_Medals` as per RDBMS because the later will work for small record sets (e.g. one - millions of rows) but it will not scale for Internet applications (SaaS, Facebook, etc)

Answer (score 3):

Go look at the [adjacency list pattern for many to many relationships](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/bp-adjacency-graphs.html) in DynamoDB. That should help you out. Also go check out Rick Houlihan's advanced data modeling talks at 2017 and 2018 reInvent.